# Simulate Web Service when it's unavailable

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

Can somebody recommend the best way to simulate web service when it's unavailable. Is there a framework, able to record and notify the users when the web service is inaccessible ?

Thanks !

Comment: On the client machine close the port to the web-service call. Instant failure just add water.

Comment: Another way would be to stop the web-service.

Comment: i want to cach the web service when it's down, so the client will have the last call of the web service existing in the cach.

Comment: So which part is the camel part? The client or the server?

Comment: The client will send a request to the web service, the apache camel will intercept the request, so if the web service is up, apache camel will return to the client the response of the web service, if the web service is down, apache camel will forward the Cache SOAP services on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the request of the client (soap request) in the database (byte array) , and saved the soap response also (if there is already a response). So, when the web service is unavailable, I search the last response existing in the database, which corresponds the request. If the remote service is not yet in operation, I used SoapUI API to generate a default response.

**See also:**

[MockResponse](http://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/mockoperations-and-responses.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've developed demos which have a failover in case of a 400 or 500 error code on the service response (due to lack of connectivity or firewalling on the customer side network). Basically, it has to be on the client code, though, where the logic parses the response and if it encounters unexpected/bad responses, has a default scenario to handle that situation.

It's not something I've done in production, but it does save some embarrassing situations in a skunkworks projects where your main application server is down or not responsive.